# AngularJS Accordion Expand All Collapse All

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to get the accordions to toggle correctly through the directive ng-click. If I have  Item one open how do I get it to expand all the accordions? Item two and Item three will continue to expand and collapse but Item one stays stagnant.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYIDDqqigPLR5qlnSfR7?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alternately you can adjust your buttons so that they just loop through the children.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemo">
  <div >
      <div class="stuff_in_the_middle" >
          <div ng-repeat="m in results" ng-click="m.open = !m.open" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <div heading="{{m.label}}" is-open="m.open" style="background-color:#d2d2d2; cursor:pointer" > 
            {{m.label}}
            </div>
            <div ng-show="m.open" style="padding:10px">
              contents
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="toggle(false)">Collapse All</span>
          <span class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="toggle(true)">Expand All</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('plunker', []);

module.controller('AccordionDemo', ['$scope', 
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.results = [
      {label: 'Item 1', open: false},
      {label: 'Item 2', open: false},
      {label: 'Item 3', open: false}
    ];

    $scope.toggle = function(state) {
      $scope.results.forEach(function(e) {
        e.open = state;
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

see it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/T6iv7mSoat9SQBwSIFJP

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with scopes. Simple rule is to never set variable value from ng-click or similar directives if you gonna use this variable outside - in parent.

It is caused by ng-repeat, which creates scope and if you will try to define new variable within it(*you are doing it, because you have used name `plunker`, instead of `opened`*), it will be defined only to current item in repeat.

You can use setter function to set it to right scope. So, here we go: http://plnkr.co/edit/h3MtKywiOaIQhpnAzWLT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still isn't working the way I would like. I don't want it to expand all when I click the accordion header only when I click the buttons. When I click the header, I want that specific accordion to open. For example, say I go to my page and I expand Item 1 accordion and then decide after looking at the contents of item 1 I would like to expand all. I click expand all and they all expand. Then, I want to collapse all so I click collapse all. You will notice in my plunker Item 1 accordion stays open. It doesn't close when I click collapse all. Thanks for the help.